# How can I keep B&O Z2 consistently connected to Airplay?

Tags: airplay, spotify

I use this excellent airplay speaker and iOS device for streaming music from Spotify. Unfortunately, the connection to Airplay reverts (timeout?) to the iPhone 6 Plus speaker after a short time. I would like it to connect by default to the Z2 and stay connected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to accomplish this without additional equipment. It seems that the networking in the Z2 is faulty. I instead connect an AirPort Express aux port to the Z2 aux port and airplay to the AirPort (after enabling airplay in the airport settings). The AirPort streams perfectly without dropping the connection and the Z2 still sounds great over aux. It'll stay connected as long as you're on the same wifi network.